# Remove outliers from Pandas Dataframe (Circular Data)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

I would like to remove outliers from Pandas dataframe using some user defined function. There are some answers to the same question I am asking in Stackoverflow but the difference is that the Data-set I have are circular data. Therefore, using Pandas built-in functions `mean()`, `std()` would not be appropriate. For example in circular data values of `355` and `5` have only a difference of 10 but linear difference gives `350`.

I have thousands of dataframes like the one below. We clearly see that `Geophone` 6 is an outlier.

```
  Geophone     azimuth  incidence      
0        1  194.765326  29.703151  
1        2  193.143982  23.380681  
2        3  199.327911  34.752212  
3        4  195.641010  49.186893  
4        5  193.479015  21.192982  
5        6    0.745142   3.410046 
6        7  192.380435  29.778807  
7        8  196.700814  19.750237
```

It can also be confirmed when plotting the data in a polar diagram.

[image]

I have written two functions `mean_angle` and `variance_angle` which calculates circular mean and variance to be applied to the data. Variance gives a value between 0 and 1. When data are close to each other Variance value gets closer to 0 and vise versa.

```
import numpy as np
def mean_angle(deg):


    deg = np.deg2rad(deg)

    S = np.array(deg)
    C = np.array(deg)
    S = S[np.isfinite(S)] #remove np.nan
    C = C[np.isfinite(C)]

    S = np.sum(np.sin(S))
    C = np.sum(np.cos(C))

    mu = np.arctan(S/C)  
    mu = np.rad2deg(mu)

    if S>0 and C>0:
        mu = mu 
    elif S>0 and C<0:
        mu = mu +180

    elif S<0 and C<0:
        mu = mu+180

    elif S<0 and C>0:
        mu = mu +360     
    return mu 


def variance_angle(deg):
    """
    deg: angles in degrees 
    """
    deg = np.deg2rad(deg)

    S = np.array(deg)
    C = np.array(deg)
    S = S[np.isfinite(S)] #remove np.nan
    C = C[np.isfinite(C)]

    length = C.size

    S = np.sum(np.sin(S))
    C = np.sum(np.cos(C))
    R = np.sqrt(S**2 + C**2)
    R_avg = R/length
    V = 1- R_avg

    return V

mean_azimuth = mean_angle(df.azimuth)
variance = variance_angle(df.azimuth)


print(mean_azimuth)
197.4122778774279
print(variance)
0.24614383460498535
```

However, when excluding row 5 from calculation, mean and variance become `195.06226604362286 , 0.0007544067627361928` respectively. The Variance is changed from `0.25` to almost `0`.

Therefore, I would like to find a way to remove any circular outlier value/s (`azimuth`) which makes circular variance high using the defined functions shown above.

In this example `incidence` is also an outlier for the same `Geophone` but It actually does not have any relation to `azimuth`. There are other data where `incidence`is within the range but `azimuth` is an outlier.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Could you just transform your circular to cartesian ones and run a traditional outlier method?

Comment: @Eulenfuchswiesel, thanks your your suggestion, for this particular df it will work but it cannot be generalised.

Comment: Just a comment, you can save a lot of lines and execution time by using pandas functions `pandas.DataFrame.mean` and `pandas.DataFrame.variance`. As the docs explain, they skip `na` values by default. checkout also `df.apply`. Almost every operation you do in numpy arrays or dataframes don't need a `for` loop

Comment: @Mstaino actually the appropriate function probably are `circmean, circvar, circstd` from `scipy.stats`. I could not find function in numpy or pandas which calculates circular statistics.

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti in that case you can use those functions; you can use the `dropna` method, which replicates a filtered dataframe /series without nan's. e.g. `scipy.stats.circmean(df.azimuth.dropna())`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do outlier detection is to compute mean and std of the data, then remove points that lie somewhere outside A*std of the mean (where you tune A to be whatever is reasonable for your data.)

So you could use your functions to compute mean and variance of your dataframe, then pass over the dataframe again to remove data points outside A*std of the mean.